# what is Main Loop Abstraction concept?

Tags: c++, c, event-handling

I am using a c/c++ API which uses concept of main loop abstraction so I am confuse how the flow  of programm works in main loop abstraction concept? is there any documentation for it ??  if anybody knows then, explain it with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's say you have one awesome library (for example OpenGL). It initializes some things via callbacks and then it enters a `while (1)` loop in which it tests for events from the users of the library.

Consider a GUI program. Each time you press a key or move your mouse or click a button an event is sent to the above loop (via a queuing mechanism or via polling, doesn't really matter now). That loop then calls the handler function associated with the callback, taking care to ensure that the call is properly done, with the proper parameters and checking.

Have you not used this, each time the programmer wanted to use a GUI application he would have to write his loop from scratch.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote if the answer was useful or to comment if you need more clarifications.

Comment: I wanted to ask if you know somewhere I could find an example of the above abstraction

Comment: The Windows event dispatch loop is an example

Comment: I meant a code example something from which I can infer what is happening. I do not use windows Operating system